# Issue in Gate in Lumen 7

Tags: laravel, authorization, lumen

I'm trying to implement authorisation on my app.

In AuthServiceProvider.php

Inside `public function boot()`

I did:

```
 
Gate::define('read-books',function ($user){
Log::Debug("debugging in define);
return $user->role === 'guest';
}


$check = Gate::allows('read-books');
$Log::Debug($check)
```

`$check` returned empty and "debugging in define" is not logged.
It seems like that lumen unable to register Gate::define

Could someone possibly point out where did I do wrong or what causes this?

Edit1: since someone asked about how I authenticate?

```
$this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
        if ($request->input('api_token')) {
            return User::where('api_token', $request->input('api_token'))->first();
        }

    });
```

Comment: where are you calling `Gate::allows`?

Comment: At first I did it in the function that called   read-books but didn't work. So, I moved it just below the Gate::define inside the boot function for testing... Still doesn't work, returning empty (undefined)

Comment: how are you authenticating the user?

Comment: Through token. Will explain a bit later. Don't have access to the code atm

Comment: @lagbox updated my post. In Edit1 I wrote how I authenticate the user